# lanzar actividad desde ImageButton

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    public void BotonAjustes()
{
    View.OnClickListener listSet = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ajustes.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    boton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    boton.setOnClickListener(listSet);
}
```

Sé que el listener en sí está bien, ya que cuando solo tenía el Toast funcionaba, pero ahora no. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que funcione? No da ningún error de compilación.

**EDIT**

Parte del logcat:

```
07-20 18:21:27.279 1534-1544/? E/RecoverySystemService: Timed out connecting to uncrypt socket
07-20 18:21:27.279 1534-1544/? E/RecoverySystemService: Failed to connect to uncrypt socket
07-20 18:21:27.280 2231-3373/? E/SystemUpdateService: Failed to call RecoverySystem.cancelScheduledUpdate
                                                      java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                          at xae.c(:com.google.android.gms:134)
                                                          at afuw.d(:com.google.android.gms:195)
                                                          at afuw.p(:com.google.android.gms:2178)
                                                          at afuw.a(:com.google.android.gms:448)
                                                          at afuw.doInBackground(:com.google.android.gms:50475)
                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                       Caused by: java.io.IOException: cancel scheduled update failed
                                                          at android.os.RecoverySystem.cancelScheduledUpdate(RecoverySystem.java:555)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                          at xae.c(:com.google.android.gms:134) 
                                                          at afuw.d(:com.google.android.gms:195) 
                                                          at afuw.p(:com.google.android.gms:2178) 
                                                          at afuw.a(:com.google.android.gms:448) 
                                                          at afuw.doInBackground(:com.google.android.gms:50475) 
                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 
                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
07-20 18:21:27.280 2231-3373/? E/SystemUpdateTask: exception trying to cancel scheduled update
                                                   java.io.IOException: Failed to invoke RecoverySystem.cancelScheduledUpdate
                                                       at xae.c(:com.google.android.gms:140)
                                                       at afuw.d(:com.google.android.gms:195)
                                                       at afuw.p(:com.google.android.gms:2178)
                                                       at afuw.a(:com.google.android.gms:448)
                                                       at afuw.doInBackground(:com.google.android.gms:50475)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Código de ajustes:

```
public class Ajustes extends Activity 
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.set);
    }
}
```

Código del layout de Ajustes (ajustes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/toolbar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeCloseDrawable"
        tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Configuración"
            android:layout_width="384dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.48"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="TextViewEdits" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/AutoLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="77dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/auto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="@string/titulo1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="TextViewEdits" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/autoarranuqe"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/interruptor"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/interruptor"
                android:text="@string/text1"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/int"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                tools:checked="false" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/WIFILayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="77dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="@string/t2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="TextViewEdits" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Wifi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText16"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                tools:text="@string/texto2"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/PlayerIDLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="103dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.13">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/playerID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gr"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="@string/texto3"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorTertiary"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:inputType="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="@string/t3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="TextViewEdits" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText17"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:text="@string/bot1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/br"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gr"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gr"
                android:layout_below="@+id/gr"
                android:text="@string/bot2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ILayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.57">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:weightSum="1"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/t0"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/Fra "
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="54dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    tools:text="@string/tex" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/En"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="44dp"
                    android:checked="true"
                    tools:text="@string/texto5"
                    android:layout_weight="0.17" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/Es"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.41"
                    android:checked="true"
                    tools:text="@string/text4" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Le estas asignado el evento `listSet` a ImageButton?

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que este es el Activity principal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:id="@+id/imb"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Vamos a la clase:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton imb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imb = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imb);
        imb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent nuevo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(nuevo);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Eso sería todo. Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
         ImageButton imageButton;
         imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
         imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ajustes.class);
            startActivity(intent);
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Si defines un listener de esta forma:

```
   View.OnClickListener listSet = new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ajustes.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
```

configura ese `listener` a tu botón, por ejemplo:

```
boton.setOnClickListener(listSet);
```

de esta forma se llamaría el `listener` al  accionar el botón.

---

Para lanzar la `Activity`, es correcto tu código:

```
  Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ajustes.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

pero recuerda que la clase Ajustes debe extender de `Activity`, `FragmentActivity` o `AppCompatActivity` y además se tiene que registrar dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>     
<manifest>

    <application
        ...
        ...

        <!-- Declaracion de Activity-->
        <activity
            android:name=".Ajustes">


    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: He probado haciendo que extienda de Activity, FragmentActivity y AppCompatActivity pero ninguna de las pruebas ha funcionado, el layout se muestra pero en cuanto lo hace la app se detiene.En cuanto al manifest, ya lo tengo añadido.

Comment: Agrega que mensaje se muestra en el LogCat por favor, puede ser que sea  otro el problema, esto dentro de la clase Ajustes.